# Using AngularFire2 to check if large amount of data exists in Firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

**Best Practice Question**

The situation:

Using Angularfir2 I am trying to find the best way to check which, if any, of a list of items that I have stored locally exist within my Firebase database. This is considering that I have a very large amount of data in my Firebase database (in this example 100k + entries but could be well over 1M) and a good deal of entries locally (in this example 200 + however it could be over 1000)

So here is an example of the Firebase database:

```
"project-1234": [
  {
    "animals" : {
      "1" : {
        "animal" : "aardvark"
      },
      ...
      "100001" : {
        "animal" : "zebra"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And here is an example of the json data stored locally:

```
[
    {"my_id"=1, "fb_id"=346, "animal"="bear"},
    ...
    {"my_id"=201, "fb_id"=45663, "animal"="water buffalo"}
]
```

Now I understand that I could simply loop over each item and then make an Angularfire2 "object" call (or even an http.get) in order to see if the item exists in the database:

```
this.data = [{...},...,{...}]; // local json data
for (let i in this.data) {
  this.fbData.object('animals\' + this.data[i].fb_id).subscribe(dataObj => {
    if (dataObj != null){
      console.log('There is a : ', this.data[i].animal);
    }
  });
}
```

or

```
this.data = [{...},...,{...}]; // local json data
for (let i in this.data) {
  let url = 'https://project-1234.firebaseio.com/animals/' + this.data[i].fb_id + '.json';
  this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((dataObj) => {
    if (dataObj != null){
      console.log('There is a : ', this.data[i].animal);
    }
  })
}
```

#### Question:

Although this is the only way I can think of to achieve my goal, even to my intermediate understanding this seems a little labor intensive not to mention slow and getting slower the more records are held locally; so I am wondering if there was a better solution out there or a best practice that can be used in a case such as this?

Many thanks in advance for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AngularFire2 (or Firebase SDK) implementation will be much more efficient that an HTTP implementation, as the requests will be pipelined -see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35932786/6680611) for more detail.

To retrieve an array of booleans indicating whether or not an item's key exists, you could do something like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray';

Observable.from(items)
  .concatMap(item => this.fbData.object(`animals/${item.fb_id}`).first().map(Boolean))
  .toArray()
  .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

Note that the `first` operator is used to retrieve a single value from the AngularFire2 object observables. Without the `first` operator, the object observables would not complete and would continue listening for and emitting changes.

It's possible that this implementation might be acceptable. You say *"seems a little labor intensive not to mention slow and getting slower"*, but have you profiled it?

Without knowing more about your application, it's difficult to offer recommendations. For example, you mention its *"getting slower the more records are held locally"*, but once you've checked whether or not a record exists in the database, can you not store knowledge of that locally? If you are able to do that, perhaps you don't have a problem?